# How to do a reverse lookup to see if a cell contains text from any cell in a list

Tags: excel

I've been using this formula to find if a cell contains text from a preset list:

`=IF(OR(COUNTIF(CELL,"*"LIST"*")), "Yes", "")`

But I want to find a way to not only return a boolean if it contains, but also the relative position on the list that the cell is (e.g. if it's the nth value on the list). I tried using something like a MATCH function on the array that the COUNTIF spits out but not good.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`=MATCH(1,0/COUNTIF(CELL,"*"&LIST&"*"))`

which may or may not require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, depending upon your version of Excel.

Also, you don't say what the result should be if more than one value from *LIST* is contained within *CELL*: the above will return the relative position of the latest.